# Deserialize JSON with mixture of dynamic and static keys

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a `JSON` object with a dynamic key for the properties I wish to map to a class. I'm uncertain how to build my class to deserialize with `JSON.NET`. I need the values from the 'results' and 'more' keys at the upper level and also the the values from the 'timesheets' key.

Here is my `JSON` data.

```
{
    "results": {
        "timesheets": {
            "7994790": {
                "id": 7994790,
                "user_id": 165502,
                "jobcode_id": 11267673,
                "start": "2019-12-20T05:48:00-05:00",
                "end": "2019-12-20T13:44:00-05:00",
                "duration": 28560,
                "date": "2019-12-20",
                "tz": -5,
                "tz_str": "tsET",
                "type": "regular",
                "location": "Android App",
                "on_the_clock": false,
                "locked": 0,
                "notes": "",
                "customfields": {
                    "20251": "",
                    "19647": "Laborer",
                    "20327": "",
                    "19648": ""
                },
                "last_modified": "2019-12-20T20:28:48+00:00",
                "attached_files": [],
                "created_by_user_id": 165502
            },
            "8087496": {
                "id": 8087496,
                "user_id": 165502,
                "jobcode_id": 2415904,
                "start": "2019-12-20T13:44:00-05:00",
                "end": "2019-12-20T15:11:00-05:00",
                "duration": 5220,
                "date": "2019-12-20",
                "tz": -5,
                "tz_str": "tsET",
                "type": "regular",
                "location": "Android App",
                "on_the_clock": false,
                "locked": 0,
                "notes": "",
                "customfields": {
                    "20251": "",
                    "19647": "Laborer",
                    "20327": "",
                    "19648": ""
                },
                "last_modified": "2019-12-20T20:28:49+00:00",
                "attached_files": [],
                "created_by_user_id": 165502
            }
        }
    },
    "more": false
}
```

And my classes as I currently have them which returns this error.

`System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: values'`

```
        public class RootObject
        {
            public Results results { get; set; }
            public bool more { get; set; }
        }

        public class Results
        {
            public Timesheets timesheets { get; set; }

        }

        public class Timesheets
        {
            public Dictionary<int, TimesheetDetails> timesheetsdetails { get; set; }
        }

        public class TimesheetDetails
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int user_id { get; set; }
            public int jobcode_id { get; set; }
            public DateTime start { get; set; }
            public DateTime end { get; set; }
            public int duration { get; set; }
            public string date { get; set; }
            public int tz { get; set; }
            public string tz_str { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string location { get; set; }
            public bool on_the_clock { get; set; }
            public int locked { get; set; }
            public string notes { get; set; }
            public DateTime last_modified { get; set; }
            public List<object> attached_files { get; set; }
            public int created_by_user_id { get; set; }
        }

            var stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result.Content);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", stuff.results.timesheets.timesheetsdetails));
```

Comment: why is customfields property in TimesheetDetails missing?

Comment: It's really unfortunate when json is misused. You might be better off working with the data as `JObject` instead of deserializing to your classes.

Comment: your json syntax is wrong first case and from are you getting result.Content?

Comment: @HameedSyed, result.Content is an IRestResponse from an API call. I have no control over the JSON data.

Comment: can you post the complete api method where you are you are deserializing the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your json is not valid. After the end of the first timesheet data, there should be a `,` You can use any json validator online simply to validate it.

And in your model the `Results` is not valid according to the json. The below one works for me.

```
public class Response
        {
            [JsonProperty("results")] public TimeSheetResponse TimeSheetResponse { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("more")] public bool More { get; set; }
        }

        public class TimeSheetResponse
        {
            [JsonProperty("timesheets")] public Dictionary<string, Timesheet> Timesheets { get; set; }
        }

        public class Timesheet
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public long Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("user_id")]
            public long UserId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("jobcode_id")]
            public long JobcodeId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("start")] public DateTimeOffset Start { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("end")] public DateTimeOffset End { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("duration")] public long Duration { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("date")] public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("tz")] public long Tz { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("tz_str")] public string TzStr { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("type")] public string Type { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("location")] public string Location { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("on_the_clock")] public bool OnTheClock { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("locked")] public long Locked { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("notes")] public string Notes { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("customfields")] public Dictionary<string, string> Customfields { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("last_modified")] public DateTimeOffset LastModified { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("attached_files")] public List<object> AttachedFiles { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("created_by_user_id")]
            public long CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
        }
```

To deserialize to Object..

```
var timeSheetResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(data);
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help.
I had removed some of the records from the JSON file and should have verified the data was still valid. My test data was valid JSON.